# Rails 6 CSV Upload wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

Hi I have a rails 6 application that has an account and a client model. The `Client` belongs to the `Account`

```rb
class Client < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :account
  has_many :sites, dependent: :destroy
    
  def item_count
    self.sites.items.count
  end
      
  def self.import(file, account_id)
    account = account.find_by(id: account_id)
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
      account.clients.create! row.to_hash
    end
  end
end

class Account < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :clients, dependent: :destroy
end
```

I want to import clients in a CSV from the account show page via a form.

```rb
<%= form_tag import_clients_path, multipart: true do %>
<%= hidden_field_tag(:account_id, value: @account) %>
<%= file_field_tag :file %>
<%= submit_tag "Import Clients" %>
<% end %>
```

The route is created here

```rb
resources :clients do
  collection {post :import}
end
```

I keep getting:

```
ArgumentError in ClientsController#import
wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2)
Extracted source (around line #9):
  7
  8
  9
  10
  11
  12
```

clients_controller

```
def import
    Client.import(params[:file])
    redirect_to account_path(@account), notice: 'Clients Imported Successfully'
  end
```

It's driving me nuts, and I am sure it's a simple error, your help is appreciated.

Comment: which is your line number 9? Is it `account.client.create! row.to_hash`? 
If yes, can you insert `Rails.logger.info(row.to_hash.inspect)` before that line and edit the post with that output?

Comment: also, since your `account` has many `clients`, shouldn't that line be `account.clients.create! row.to_hash` (plural clients)

Comment: @kiddorrails line 9 is  def self.import(file, account_id)

Comment: Could you add the code for the `import` method in `ClientsController` to your question? The error being reported is in the controller, not the model.

Comment: @rmlockerd updated, thanks for the edits to my question also, it was super late and i was a bit lackluster

Comment: `Client.import` takes two parameters (file and account ID), but when you call it in your controller you only pass one parameter (`params[:file]`)

Comment: I knew as soon as you mentioned it. my focus was on the model and missed it, thank you